# Pikaday calendar date format not working

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I'm using the Pikaday calendar library but the date format seems to be being ignored. I have this code:

```
<script>
var picker = new Pikaday(
{
    field: document.getElementById('dayDate'),
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: new Date(2017, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
    yearRange: [2017, 2020],
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    bound: false,
    container: document.getElementById('date-container'),
});
</script>
```

This outputs the date in this format 'Thu May 25 2017' I need it to be in the format '2017-05-25'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Pikaday documentation, you have to reference [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) to make the custom date formatting work.

From the [docs](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#configuration):

> format: the default output format for .toString() and field value (requires Moment.js for custom formatting)

Make sure to reference the Moments.js library **before** Pikaday.